# Forward port to another Ip/port

Tags: networking, routing, tcpip, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

I recently found out that my ISP disables port 135.  I have a server and personal computer behind my router.  A friend and I are working on a programming project and are running into some sql issues because of this blocked port.  For him to be able to access everything, I have dynadns configured

Personal Computer: 192.168.1.100 
Server Computer: 192.168.1.110

Is there a way for me to forward localhost traffice from port 135 to say port 8081 and then have my server take incoming requests from port 8081 to 135?  I have heard a little bit about ssh tunneling but it seems odd to be using Putty to login to my local machine where the ssh server is running to forward ports.

Any advice would be very helpful.

Thanks

EDIT:  I am using a router with dd-wrt installed and have installed the vpn addon.  I was trying to get VPN working on my windows 2003 computer but was having problems with the GRE protocol not being configured.  I will attempt the vpn option with my router and post my results later today.

Comment: you can just NAT really... VPN is way too overkill

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to set up a **VPN** on one of your computers, and have the other one log into that one.  That way they will appear to be on the same subnet, and have full access to each other without exposing vulnerable ports to the world.

A really good Open Source VPN is **OpenVPN**.  I've only used the server under linux though, so I can't comment on how easy it is to set up on windows.

Another option is to flash your router with **dd-wrt** firmware.  There is a version that includes an OpenVPN server, and would connect your entire network to his.

Answer (score 4):

I've used [PortMapper](http://www.analogx.com/contents/download/Network/pmapper/Freeware.htm) by AnalogX to do this exact thing.  It is very easy to setup and run.

Comment: Thanks for the link. This is exactly what I was looking for. Works perfectly for my case (doesn't involve routing through the internet, so doesn't need security).

Comment: just saying, it's not much a port-forwarder but an actual proxy which listens to ports you define and connect to the destination socket (it matters when the forwarding purpose is for network tests for example..)

Answer (score 1):

Port 135 is used by active directory and other Microsoft services.  It is unlikely you'll find a good method for redirecting that port either on the client or the server.  You would be better off giving your friend remote access to a virtual PC on your network, using some kind of VPN, or otherwise getting him onto your network where these port assignments do not need to be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Your ISP blocking 135 for good reason. That port, and port 445, are two of the major vectors for the continued attacks by malware and worms against Windows machines.

If you need access to those ports, can I suggest ssh forwarding, or using a VPN?

Answer (score 0):

I would seriously consider setting up a site-site VPN instead of monkeying around with ports.  Most home routers on the market support it now.

Answer (score 0):

Actualy, we don't know what router/gateway you're using so It'll be difficult to help you.

BUT, most router/gateway have option to forward a port to another.

Answer (score 0):

Try [rinetd](http://linux.die.net/man/8/rinetd).

This redirects TCP traffic from one port on a computer to another.

Answer (score 0):

[tcpproxy](http://www.quietsche-entchen.de/cgi-bin/wiki.cgi/proxies/TcpProxy) should do what you need. I'm guessing that your server is listening on TCP/135, and you want to punch a hole in your firewall and expose TCP/8081 on your workstation to the outside world. In that case, you would run tcpproxy on your workstation with a config file that looked something like this:

```
port 8081
interface eth0
    server xyz:135
```

Of course, replace 'eth0' with whatever your interface name is, and 'xyz' with your server's actual hostname.

Answer (score 0):

Other solutions may work for this but keep in mind that Windows hangs on to port 135 pretty strongly for filesharing and it's use of the port may make redirecting it difficult. On Windows, there is a good SSH guide to port forwarding at http://www.bitvise.com/port-forwarding and BitVise makes, in my opinion, good SSH client and server products for Windows. Their client makes port forwarding easy and graphical, although the same can be done with PuTTY for free on the client side. I would strongly recommend encrypting forwarded traffic with SSH if you control both endpoints, vs. running a public server for anyone to connect to (which may not be as private). Port 135 would definitely be something I'd want to encrypt if I opened it to the internet, even on a different port!

Answer (score 0):

Port Forwarding in DD-Wrt can probably do what you want it to do if I'm understanding you correctly and use NA.

Say I had an httpd running on port 80 running inside my network, but that was blocked by my ISP, I used Port Forwarding in DD-Wrt to map a different external port to get directed to 80.

So effectively, from outside the network, I could connect to mydomain.dynalias.net:8081 and my server would stay on port 80.

It's been a few years since I've used DD-Wrt, so I'll point to here for the exact documentation:
http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Port_Forwarding